# C# JSON request

Tags: c#, json, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am currently using the `HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse` to make web service calls. The response is then deserialized into a custom class I have written.

The program works fine when the response is fully populated, the problem comes when some of the custom lists defined are returned empty. Is there something I am missing? I have tried setting explicit constructors (commented out below) but to no avail!

WebServiceCall:

```
private RootObject GetWebServiceResult(string wUrl)
    {

        HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(wUrl);
        httpWReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Token dd88013048d84e1c9e9e5969854e667e");
        HttpWebResponse httpWResp = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
        RootObject jsonResponse = null;

        try
        {
            //Test the connection
            if (httpWResp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {

                Stream responseStream = httpWResp.GetResponseStream();
                string jsonString;

                //Set jsonString using a stream reader
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    reader.Close();
                }

                //Deserialize our JSON
                JavaScriptSerializer sr = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                //JSON string comes in with a leading and trailing " that need to be removed for parsing to work correctly
                //The JSON here is serialized weird, normally you would not need this trim
                jsonResponse = sr.Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonString);

            }
            //Output connection error message
            else
            {
                FailComponent(httpWResp.StatusCode.ToString());

            }
        }
        //Output JSON parsing error
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            FailComponent(e.ToString());
        }
        return jsonResponse;

    }
```

Custom Class:

```
#region JSON Class
//Class to hold our work group metrics

public class Task2
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string uuid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public Task2 task { get; set; }
}

public class WorkedHour
{
    public DateTime start { get; set; }
    public bool inTransit { get; set; }
    public DateTime end { get; set; }
}

public class Crew
{
    public List<WorkedHour> workedHours { get; set; }
    //public List<WorkedHour> workedHours { set { new List<WorkedHour>(); } get { return workedHours; } }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string uuid { get; set; }

    /*public Crew()
    {
        List<WorkedHour> workedHours = new List<WorkedHour>();
    }*/
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Task> tasks { get; set; }
    //public List<Task> tasks { set { new List<Task>(); } get { return tasks; } }
    public List<Crew> crew { get; set;}
    //public List<Crew> crew { set { new List<Crew>(); } get { return crew;} }
    /*public RootObject()
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        List<Crew> crew = new List<Crew>();
    }*/
}
```

I am debugging an issue when the `crew[]` list is return `null`.

Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Example Response:

```
"{\"startedOn\": \"2016-10-11T10:19:10+00:00\", \"tasks\": [{\"note\": \"\", \"assignee\": {\"uuid\": \"example\"}, \"task\": {\"description\": \"Example Desc\", \"uuid\": \"example\", \"name\": \"Example Name\"}, \"done\": true, \"uuid\": \"example\", \"attachments\": [{\"mimetype\": \"application/pdf\", \"caption\": \"\", \"createdDate\": \"2016-10-10T13:31:37+00:00\", \"uuid\": \"example\", \"name\": \"document.pdf\"}, {\"mimetype\": \"application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12\", \"caption\": \"\", \"createdDate\": \"2016-10-10T13:31:37+00:00\", \"uuid\": \"example\", \"name\": \"document.xlsm\"}, {\"mimetype\": \"application/pdf\", \"caption\": \"\", \"createdDate\": \"2016-10-10T13:31:37+00:00\", \"uuid\": \"example\", \"name\": \"document.pdf\"}, {\"mimetype\": \"application/pdf\", \"caption\": \"\", \"createdDate\": \"2016-10-10T13:31:37+00:00\", \"uuid\": \"example\", \"name\": \"document.pdf\"}], \"items\": [], \"unitPrice\": 0.00000, \"unitCost\": 0.00000, \"asset\": null}, {\"note\": \"\", \"assignee\": {\"uuid\": \"example\"}, \"task\": {\"description\": \"Example Desc\", \"uuid\": \"example\", \"name\": \"Example Name\"}, \"done\": true, \"uuid\": \"example\", \"attachments\": [{\"mimetype\": \"image/jpeg\", \"caption\": \"\", \"createdDate\": \"2016-10-11T11:12:38+00:00\", \"uuid\": \"example\", \"name\": \"document.jpg\"}], \"items\": [], \"unitPrice\": 0.00000, \"unitCost\": 0.00000, \"asset\": null}, {\"note\": \"\", \"assignee\": {\"uuid\": \"example\"}, \"task\": {\"description\": \"\", \"uuid\": \"example\", \"name\": \"Example Name\"}, \"done\": false, \"uuid\": \"example\", \"attachments\": [], \"items\": [], \"unitPrice\": 0.00000, \"unitCost\": 0.00000, \"asset\": null}], \"description\": \"SO742441 P129 B1 \", \"revenue\": 0.00000, \"signature\": null, \"jobId\": \"J176\", \"invoice\": null, \"jobLead\": {\"emailAddress\": \"example@test.com\", \"telno\": \"000000000\", \"surname\": \"Doe\", \"uuid\": \"example\", \"name\": \"John\"}, \"scheduledOn\": \"2016-10-11T11:15:00+00:00\", \"labor\": [], \"pre_signature\": null, \"customer\": {\"uuid\": \"example\", \"name\": \"Example Name\", \"customerId\": 1}, \"estDuration\": 90, \"uuid\": \"example\", \"createdOn\": \"2016-10-10T13:32:53+00:00\", \"crew\": [], \"state\": \"completed\", \"uuid\": \"example\"}], \"state\": [\"completed\"], \"contact\": null, \"asset\": null, \"completedOn\": \"2016-10-11T11:12:59+00:00\", \"customFields\": {\"job_type\": \"Example Type\", \"example\": \"Order\", \"example\": \"2016-10-14\"}, \"location\": {\"uuid\": \"example\", \"locality\": \"Test\", \"country\": \"United Kingdom\", \"region\": null, \"postcode\": \"TEST\", \"streetName\": \"Test Road\", \"name\": \"Example Name\"}}"
```

Comment: without showing the json which you receive, we can't help you.

Comment: You don't need to use reader.Close() inside `using` statement. `using` statement closes the resource for you. It's like try-finally where in finally you have reader.Close().

Comment: @mybirthname I've updated it with an example response. Apologies is not very readable.